# Broken grub configure on Ubuntu 19.10 with ZFS

Tags: grub2, 19.10, zfs

my apt is broken due failing grub configure.

**It looks like grub is trying to discover linux-images inside my zfs snapshots**:

```
Setting up linux-image-5.3.0-23-generic (5.3.0-23.25) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.3.0-23-generic (5.3.0-23.25) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-23-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_q9qi62
cryptsetup: WARNING: Couldn't determine root device
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
I: (UUID=a9d90fb7-5154-4897-9a2e-90c040c8ee90)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.3.0-18-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_q9qi62
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.3.0-18-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_q9qi62
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.3.0-19-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_q9qi62
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.3.0-19-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_q9qi62
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.3.0-23-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_q9qi62
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.3.0-23-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_q9qi62
/etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs: 338: .: Can't open /tmp/zfsmnt.rcbjOa/etc/.zfs/snapshot/autobackup-sd25sfd-2019-10-23--17-41-11/os-release
umount: /tmp/zfsmnt.rcbjOa: target is busy.
rmdir: failed to remove '/tmp/zfsmnt.rcbjOa': Device or resource busy
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.3.0-23-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.3.0-23-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.3.0-23-generic
```

I'm using default ubuntu19.10 zfs configuration by installer.

Comment: I am also having this problem, have you resolved it?

Comment: I may be misreading this, but I don't see how it is searching within the snapshots - just within the dataset. Or is the underscore somehow like the `@` separator here, although [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1448/gbcpt.html#scrolltoc) allow the underscore as part of the dataset name?

Answer (score 0):

Old but unasnered, so...

I have just encountered this issue. It turned out to be sophos AV scanner automatically scanning new mount points under /tmp. This was causing a lock on the file system. So disabling sophos while running the updates fixed the issue.

Adding the following hooks should also take care of future issues

```
root@:/etc/grub.d# ls -tlr *sophos*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 45 Feb  9 13:16 01_sophos
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 46 Feb  9 13:16 999_sophos
root@:/etc/grub.d# cat *sophos*
#!/bin/sh

systemctl stop sophos-spl.service
#!/bin/sh

systemctl start sophos-spl.service
root@abl-nonprod-agent-02:/etc/grub.d#
```