# Ubuntu eoan failure with grub-probe on ZFS root partition

Tags: grub2, zfs

new user here. I tried to install Ubuntu again after a long time and used ZFS as root partition to try it out. Have encountered some issues which manifest when installing software via apt:

```
user@T440S:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.3.0-42 linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-42-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-42-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,664 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up linux-image-5.3.0-53-generic (5.3.0-53.47) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.3.0-53-generic (5.3.0-53.47) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.3.0-53-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda3
I: (UUID=8d9373be-c8cb-4b3d-a6b2-4eb3efc268a5)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qojhyv'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.3.0-53-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.3.0-53-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.3.0-53-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
user@T440S:/dev$ sudo grub-probe /
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qojhyv'.
```

I have not been able to figure out why it can't probe the root pool location. There are some similar questions on AskUbuntu but none exactly like this problem. For example:

[This user had similar for seems more related to crypto or snapshots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190561/broken-grub-configure-on-ubuntu-19-10-with-zfs)

[This one is closer but env var did not fix and struggling with the symlink suggestion because the rpool format shows no where](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827126/zfs-grub-probe-error-failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-dev-disk-name)

There are more similar launchpad issues with ubuntu but not sure how to work around:

[This seems like a good match... but is old an allegedly fixed long ago](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1687664)

[This also seems like a good match... links to another issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1855605)

[This allegedly is a fix but not sure how to apply it. There are no lines where it tries to use grub_probe](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1867910)

I am not really sure how to resolve the issue at this point.

Any ideas?